# Replace values in multiple columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, string

```
data = {'Cat':  ['A','A','B','B','B','B'],
        'L1': ['0','0','0','0','0','0'],
        'L2': ['0','0','0','0','0','0'],
        'L3': ['0','0','0','0','0','0'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Cat','L1','L2','L3'])
```

Where 'Cat' is B, I would like to replace values in L1, L2, L3 to `nan` or `''`.

```
df[['L1','L2','L3']] = np.where(df[['Cat'] == 'B', '')
```

the above did not work for me as I don't have `y`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.Cat == "B", "L1":"L3"] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Cat   L1   L2   L3
0   A    0    0    0
1   A    0    0    0
2   B  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   B  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   B  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   B  NaN  NaN  NaN
```